# contar sabado y domingo en un rango de fechas con datapicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Como puedo saber cuandos sabados y domingos hay en un rango de fechas
**01-01-2017 & 20-01-2017** (por ejemplo), sabiendo que datapicker (bootstrap) tiene un

arreglo que toma =>
domingo[0] [lunes[1] martes[2] miercoles[3] jueves[4] viernes[5] sabado[6]

Comment: Como rango de fecha toma el primer sabado, o sea si la fecha es 01-01-2017 y el sabado cae el 5 toma el 05-01-2017. Después saca la diferencia de días entre el primer sabado y la fecha final y la dividís por siete. Si el numero no es exacto redondeas para arriba

Comment: el principal problema es que las fechas siempre son aleatorias, siempre hay un rango diferente.

Comment: Si eso no cambia en nada, con una función que realice eso te va a servir para todas las fechas

Comment: Ahí edite mi respuesta agregando informacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes una solución:

```
function cuentaFindes(){
    var inicio = new Date("2017-02-24"); //Fecha inicial
    var fin = new Date("2017-03-10"); //Fecha final
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(fin.getTime() - inicio.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); //Días entre las dos fechas
    var cuentaFinde = 0; //Número de Sábados y Domingos
    var array = new Array(diffDays);

    for (var i=0; i < diffDays; i++) 
    {
        //0 => Domingo - 6 => Sábado
        if (inicio.getDay() == 0 || inicio.getDay() == 6) {
            cuentaFinde++;
        }
        inicio.setDate(inicio.getDate() + 1);
    }

   return cuentaFinde;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @cnbandicoot, ahorita mismo lo pruebo.

Comment: Damn, buena logica gracias (Y)

Comment: Encontre 2 cositas:
No es el formato que indicaba al inicio y para las fechas "2016-12-28" y "2017-01-02" siguiendo ese formato, retorna 1, cuando debería ser 2. sl2

Comment: @FelixApaza  1- Puede tener un sencillo algoritmo que cambie de formato las fechas. 2- Te equivocas, retorna 2.

Comment: No creo que cambie el resultado por navegador, retorna 1 .

Comment: @FelixApaza No creo tampoco que mi *jsFiddle* me esté engañando: https://jsfiddle.net/5c0oy2jy/1/

Comment: Yo veo ahi que sale 1, XD

Comment: @FelixApaza Puede ser debido a tu zona horaria ¿?

Comment: Eso pensaba, pero no debería influenciar ya que son dos fechas fijas, supongo que es por el getDate() . será cosa de esperar que otras personas prueben tu código. estoy en GMT-5 y me sale 1 en consola de Chrome, Safari y tu jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Esto creo que seria lo que buscas:

Recordar que la semana cuenta desde 0; Domingo =0 y Sábado =6

```
function contadorSabadosYDomingos(fechaInicial,fechaFinal){
fechaInicial = fechaInicial.split("-");
fechaFinal = fechaFinal.split("-");

var dtInicial = new Date(fechaInicial[2], fechaInicial[1] - 1, fechaInicial[0]);
var dtFinal =new Date(fechaFinal[2], fechaFinal[1] - 1, fechaFinal[0]);

var contadorDias = 0;
while(dtInicial <=dtFinal){
    if(dtInicial.getDay()===0||dtInicial.getDay()===6){
     console.log("dia contado:"+dtInicial);
     contadorDias++;
    }
dtInicial = new Date(dtInicial.getTime()+86400000);// se agrega un dia

}
return contadorDias;
}
```

Comment: ahorita mismo lo pruebo, gracias @Felix

Comment: @matteo no olvides probar en los cambios de mes y cambios de un año a otro año, seguro otras respuestas fallaran ahí, por eso de forma absoluta es mejor usar Date.getTime()
Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución seria que asignes en una variable la fecha de inicio, haces un ciclo de repetición donde le vas a ir sumando un día a esa variable y vas a ir preguntando si la fecha es sábado, de ser así le agregas un +1 al contador, el ciclo termina cuando la fecha que le estas agregando un día llega a la fecha de fin. Te quedaría algo así en C#, tendrías que pasarlo no mas

```
public int DiasSabados(DateTime inicio, DateTime fin)
    {
        int contadorSabados = 0;
        while (inicio < fin)
        { 
            if ( inicio.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                contadorSabados++;
            } 
        inicio = inicio.AddDays(1);
        }
         return contadorSabados;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
while(inicio < fin) 
{
    if (inicio.getDay() == saturday)
    {
        contadorSabados++;
    }
    inicio.setDate(inicio.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Comment: No creo que poner una respuesta en otro lenguaje, le ayude.

Comment: La logica es la misma que en JavaScript, solo tiene que cambiar un poco la sintaxis @cnbandicoot

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti perdone mi intromisión, pero, en todo caso el OP ha etiquetado su pregunta con el lenguaje javascript, por lo tanto la(s) respuestas deberían estar con el lenguaje que usa el OP.

Comment: Gracias @AlejandroRicotti ahorita mismo lo pruebo.